# How to make test case parameters invisible or read-only in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I need to give a suite of test cases (Selenium IDE) to a client but I need the case parameters to be invisible or read-only to the client.

Is there any possibility of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Its quite unclear what you are referring to when saying "parameter". I assume these is the data (ex. values provided to your test cases, like userid, password, etc).

If you have inserted these value in testng.xml or as dataprovider in the code, then **NO**. There is no way you can hide it from client.

Instead you can fetch this data as from an external excel file and mark it as write protected. This will solve the your problem